# How to handle data from codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

sorry for my english. I have a problem. There is a text field, where user enters commands in some language, for example - javascript. When sending, in response to receiving the result of this command (from a similar tryruby.org). To do this, I use codemirror. Interested in a moment: how to handle the code and return the result? Is there a built-in methods for codemirror such actions (in the documentation is not clear written)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> how to handle the code and return the result?  Is there a built-in methods for codemirror such actions?

I assume you are asking whether CodeMirror has built-in functionality to evaluate code? The answer is no.

You have to do that part yourself, which isn't too complicated:

```
var code = codemirror.getValue(); // get value from CodeMirror
var func = new Function(code);    // create new function to evaluate code
func();                           // evaluate code
```

See the [MDN documentation of **`Function`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

I'm not sure what kind of "result" you want to show. That really depends on your specific use case, but I hope this helps you get started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I want to know how sites, like codecademy, codeschool or tryruby evaluate code? For example, I enter: "Some text".reverse() in text field, click Enter and get the result - "xtet emoS". It is from [tryruby.org](http://tryruby.org). Based on your answer, for each case I must to write a function to evaluate code. This is the only solution or there is any ready-made solutions?

Comment: As I said, it depends on what exactly you want to do. If you are trying to build a REPL, then you might want to have a look at how http://repl.it/ does it for JavaScript. Or have a look at http://babeljs.io/repl/. Both projects are on GitHub.